# Creating a new project/site in Githubs Atom Editor

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext3, atom-editor

I've downloaded **Githubs Atom Editor** and I can't seem to figure out any way on creating projects.

I currently use **Sublime Text 3**, I've added some packages to it which allow FTP and I'm able to create Directories and sites as it has a built in Project Manager.

I've been looking over the internet for a while now and can't find any help from the following.

- Does **Atom** have a built in FTP?
- How to create projects/sites like in **Sublime Text 3**?
- Does everything sync to your **Github**?

Apologies is this has been asked or seems irrelevant but I am looking for assistance in using the new Atom Editor.

Answer (score 2):

Out of the box atom does provide some project view if you open (<kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>O</kbd>) a directory instead of a file:

[image]

I've recently been trying new editors as well. I have been switching between Atom, Brackets, and Sublime Text 3. They have many similarities, as you probably have noticed. Atom doesn't come with very much out of the box, just like Sublime Text, but just like Sublime Text it's highly extendable using its built in package manager.

Atom's Package Manager is found in the Preferences (<kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>,</kbd>). Then select the Packages tab on the left.

Currently there isn't an ftp package, but chances are it's only a matter of time. If you're using FTP for deployment git provides a much better/safer workflow with not a whole lot of overhead to get set up....But that's another topic I won't dive into here.

There are a couple pretty nice project manager packages that would give you a similar experience to Sublime Text's projects:

[image]

As far as git integration goes it's a similar situation to project management. It has a few nice features built in (Open in Github, highlighting files with pending changes, etc...), but there are a few nice packages that can really make Atom's git integrations pretty verbose.

Hope this helps, good luck

Comment: Thanks MattDMo for cleaning my answer up. How do you embed the keyboard key images?

Comment: in case you hadn't figured it out yet:  `<kbd>key ...</kbd>` :)